# Do I need to split the question in 3?

Tags: discussion

Well, my [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/33462/which-position-in-bus-we-sit-that-we-receive-least-damage-upon-accident#comment73953_33462) about car crash is off topic or it is so stupid that no one would answer?

If this is so important to keep only one question in a question so that we can't answer question with different scenario, should we split the question in 3?

In other words, if I split the question in 3, are question okay? Wouldn't it be pretty stupid?

Answer (score 3):

No, a question probably wouldn't get closed if it simply needed to be split. I believe that question is actually off topic, in that it can't be answered using physical principles. Any question about car crashes that would be appropriate on this site would have to be much more specific.